# how to count the fetched rows by sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sqldatasource

```vb
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim LoginChecker As New SqlDataSource()
    LoginChecker.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("A1ConnectionString1").ToString()
    LoginChecker.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text
    LoginChecker.SelectCommand = "SELECT username FROM A1login WHERE username=@username AND password=@password"
    LoginChecker.SelectParameters.Add("username", username.Text)
    LoginChecker.SelectParameters.Add("password", password.Text)
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
    Try
        rowsAffected = LoginChecker.<what i have to write here>
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Server.Transfer("LoginSucessful.aspx")
    Finally
        LoginChecker = Nothing
    End Try
    username.Text = rowsAffected
    ' If rowsAffected = 1 Then
    'Server.Transfer("A1success.aspx")
    '   Else
    'Server.Transfer("A1failure.aspx")
    '  End If

End Sub
```

this is the code for login.aspx.vb
  it checks the username and password in the database and redirecrs to respective page on the basis of rows returned. i'm having problem in finding a right function in the sqldatareader namespace so that it counts the number of rows affected. Can anybody tell me the function I should use there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Selected` event of the SqlDataSource Control.
The event is raised after the Select operation is complete.

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    lblRecordCount.Text = "Record Count: " + e.AffectedRows.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView d =(DataView) SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    Response.Write(d.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx) will return an IEnumerable. You you can [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)().[Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) on this.

Comment: thanks . but, can u plz elaborate what you are saying     .   correct me if i'm wrong   --------  objective is to count the number of  IEnumerables   so to do that  how to code  .. is it ToList(LoginChecker).Count

Answer (score 0):

The SQLDataReader doesn't have a row count property the easiest way to get the count would be to do this...

```
int rowCount = 0;
if (dr.HasRows)  
{  
    while (dr.Read())  
        {  
            rowCount++;
            dgResults.DataSource = dr;  
            dgResults.DataBind();  
            dgResults.Visible = true;  
        }  

lblMsg.Text = rowCount.ToString();
dr.Close();
```

Comment: no man there is an error , there is nothing like HasRows        can u plz verify and tell me  . shall i need to include any other specific namespace .

Answer (score 0):

[You should read this page](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx&ei=RtfcTOL5KYzUvQOnhp3MCQ&usg=AFQjCNEFcnIppZDt3hVYsUB99PMOITqP4Q&sig2=cQRh80efOevYbz89p7UbkA)

```
 Namespace:  System.Data 
 Assembly:  System.Data (in System.Data.dll)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch your rows, declare `sqlcommand` and `sqlconnection`:

```
Dim cmd as sqlcommand
Dim con as new sqlconnection("Ur connection string")
cmd.connection=con
cmd.commandtext="SELECT count(username) FROM A1login WHERE username=@username AND password=@password"
Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.executescalar()
```

In `rowsaffected` you will get the total number of rows fetched

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM A1login WHERE username=@username AND password=@password"
```

This Code return Count value